# Android push notification not working with some phones

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to use push notification in my app. I copied and pasted the sample codes from the site that services push notifications. When I send pushes, the pushes just would come to my phone and emulator and not to all phones the app installed on them.
If the code has problems, why my phone receives the pushes? if not, why the other phones can't receive?
(I can see correctly how many users installed the app in my panel.)

What's wrong in your idea?

you can see my codes below.

**Receiver Class :**

```
public class myReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long reqId= intent.getLongExtra("RequestId", -1);
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Message");

    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}}
```

**myApplicaton Class :**

```
public class myApplicaton extends SlsApplication implements IFinishedInit {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    String sid = "f4439879-8bc1-4c01-87ce-8e98d0f76ccc";

    SLS.init(this,sid,this);

}

@Override
public void finishedInit(int i) {
    switch (i){
        case SLS.RESULT_OK:
            Log.i("baas", "RESULT_OK");
            break;
        case SLS.RESULT_FAILED:
            Log.i("baas", "RESULT_FAILED");
            break;}
    }
}
```

**manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushnotif.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.pushnotif.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<application
    android:name=".myApplicaton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="ir.sls.android.slspush.Receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.pushnotif" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="ir.sls.android.slspush.GcmIntentService" />

    <receiver android:name="ir.sls.android.slspush.NetWatcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".myReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="com.example.pushnotif" />
            <action android:name="ir.sls.android.slspush.ActionSlsPushReceived" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are working with. We cannot provide a proper answer without looking at your potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether all the unreceived mobiles generating GCM registratio id..